# Sort Perl array in place

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

I have a reference to an array (called `$intervals`) and I would like to sort the values in this array. It's possible that there could be a huge number of values in the array, so I would prefer not to copy the values. My current approach is this.

```
sub by_position
{
  $a->start <=> $b->start ||
  $a->end   <=> $b->end
}
my @sorted_intervals = sort by_position (@$intervals);
```

However, if I understand Perl correctly this will indeed copy all of the values in the array. Is that right? If so, is there a way that I can do an in-place sort of an array (using a reference to that array)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Perl allows arrays to be sorted in-place with the idiom `@arr = sort @arr`. Contrary to the normal behavior of the assignment operator, no copies will be made in this case. However, this optimization is limited to normal array variables; it won't work with array references:

Let's look under the hood by using the `-MO=Concise` option. First, we do normal in-place sorting to see what we'd expect:

```
$ perl -E'say $^V'
v5.18.2
$ perl -MO=Concise -e'my @arr; @arr = sort @arr'
8  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{ ->3
3     <0> padav[@arr:1,2] vM/LVINTRO ->4
4     <;> nextstate(main 2 -e:1) v:{ ->5
-     <1> ex-aassign vKS/64 ->8
-        <1> ex-list lK ->-
5           <0> pushmark s ->6
7           <@> sort lK/INPLACE ->8
6              <0> padrange[@arr:1,2] l/1 ->7
-              <0> padav[@arr:1,2] lRM* ->7
-        <1> ex-list lK ->-
-           <0> ex-pushmark s ->-
-           <0> ex-padav lRM* ->-
-e syntax OK
```

Interesting: `<@> sort lK/INPLACE ->8`, which seems to sort in place. Now let's do the same thing with references:

```
$ perl -MO=Concise -e'my $ref; @$ref = sort @$ref'
e  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{ ->3
3     <0> padsv[$ref:1,2] vM/LVINTRO ->4
4     <;> nextstate(main 2 -e:1) v:{ ->5
d     <2> aassign[t4] vKS/COMMON ->e
-        <1> ex-list lK ->a
5           <0> pushmark s ->6
9           <@> sort lK ->a
6              <0> pushmark s ->7
8              <1> rv2av[t3] lK/1 ->9
7                 <0> padsv[$ref:1,2] s ->8
-        <1> ex-list lK ->d
a           <0> pushmark s ->b
c           <1> rv2av[t2] lKRM*/1 ->d
b              <0> padsv[$ref:1,2] sM/DREFAV ->c
-e syntax OK
```

I do not see an inplace flag in `<@> sort lK ->a`. So the optimization only seems to work when using the same variable, not when using the same array. But this means we can sort array references in place if we alias an array variable to the array referenced by some scalar (using [Data::Alias](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Alias)):

```
perl -MData::Alias -MO=Concise -e'my $ref; alias my @arr = @$ref; @arr = sort @arr'
e  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{ ->3
3     <0> padsv[$ref:1,3] vM/LVINTRO ->4
4     <;> nextstate(main 2 -e:1) v:{ ->5
-     <1> entersub vKS/INARGS ->a
         ...
a     <;> nextstate(main 3 -e:1) v:{ ->b
-     <1> ex-aassign vKS/64 ->e
-        <1> ex-list lK ->-
b           <0> pushmark s ->c
d           <@> sort lK/INPLACE ->e
c              <0> padrange[@arr:2,3] l/1 ->d
-              <0> padav[@arr:2,3] lRM* ->d
-        <1> ex-list lK ->-
-           <0> ex-pushmark s ->-
-           <0> ex-padav lRM* ->-
-e syntax OK
```

… and the inplace-flag is there again `<@> sort lK/INPLACE ->e` :-)

This means that [Eric Strom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163208/1521179) is incorrect.

Comment: Tip: `-MO=Concise,-exec` shows in `exec` order, but also hides the opcodes that were optimized away (those with `-` in the first column), so it can be easier to read.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960545/sorting-a-perl-array-reference-arrayref-in-place

Answer (score 20):

Since Perl 5.8.4, the in-place sort `@a = sort @a` is optimized. See the links below for details:

[Performance Enhancements in perl584delta](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perl584delta#Performance_Enhancements)

http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/fe1bc4cf71e7b04d33e679798964a090d9fa7b46?f=pp_sort.c

```
+    /* The optimiser converts "@a = sort @a" to "sort \@a";
+     * in case of a tied @a, pessimise: push (@a) onto stack, then assign
+     * the result back to @a at the end of this function */
```

So you should be able to write:

```
@$intervals = sort by_position @$intervals
```

And in Perl's later than 5.8.3 you will see reduced memory usage (and preservation of aliasing for the rare times it matters).

Comment: do you know what algorithm is used for `sort \@a`? I assume the second link might yield some sort of an answer but don't have the time to read through the diffs at the moment :(

Comment: @DVK => as far as I can tell it is using an in-place mergesort.  The optimization occurs in a wrapper to `sortsv` so it seems perl always does an in-place sort, but usually on a copy.

Comment: @DVK I believe from reading the code that it will default to using mergesort unless otherwise specified when Perl is built.  Merge sort and quick sort are both implemented in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification after `you should be able to write`!

Comment: While the in-place optimization exists, it is only applied when the argument and the lvalue are the same array variable. As of perl 5.18.2, it is _not applied to references_ – see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24960868/1521179).

Answer (score 2):

The second example will create a new reference:

```
$x = [ qw( a c b ) ]; say $x; @$x = sort @$x; say $x; $x = [sort @$x]; say $x
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163064/sort-perl-array-in-place/24960868#24960868).

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960545/sorting-a-perl-array-reference-arrayref-in-place