# Sorting a Perl array reference (arrayref) in place

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, reference

I'm aware that since Perl 5.8.4, one can do an efficient array sort in place with:

@a = sort @a;

As detailed in [Sort Perl array in place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163064/sort-perl-array-in-place)

But can one similarly (and efficiently!) sort an array reference in place?

```
@$a = sort @$a; # makes me think there would be duplication and inefficiency
$a = [sort @$a]; # Looks similarly nuts!
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The question you linked to also asks about sorting a reference, so this question is a duplicate (don't worry, that's not a bad thing). I've voted to close this as a dupe of the linked post; if it ends up being closed, I'll request that the answers from both posts be merged, since @amon's answer corrects an inaccuracy in the accepted answer on the other post.