# how to sort an array by a selected value in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

i have strings inside an array in this way

```
/hello/Stack/oveflow 14
/hello/Stack/oveflow 11
/hello/Stack/oveflow 12
/hello/Stack/oveflow 166
/hello/Stack/oveflow 1
/hello/Stack/oveflow 2
/hello/Stack/oveflow 5
```

i have to sort by the last number

is it possible to use  [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `sort` is exactly what you need. Just provide the code block to compare two elements:

```
my @sorted = sort { ($a =~ /[0-9]+/g)[-1]
                    <=>
                    ($b =~ /[0-9]+/g)[-1]
                  } @array;
```

`<=>` does the numeric comparison. The matching returns all the numbers in the string, `[-1]` selects the last one.

Comment: thanks a lot, sort can't be used for the given array, i mean,it always create a new array sorted?

Comment: @YokupokuMaioku: For `@array = sort { ...} @array;`, Perl does the in-place sort. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5163064/1030675

Comment: Also note. If you do some transformation with the data. In this case running a regex on $a and $b, it can make sense to use the [Schwartzian Transformation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483475/schwartzian-transform-in-perl) for performance