# Sort Archive::Zip members in-place

Tags: perl

I need to sort array members in-place using Perl, but I can not achieve this without using `Data::Alias` as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163064/sort-perl-array-in-place/24960868#24960868) answer.

Is it possible to achieve this without additional Perl libraries that are not included by default in Debian distribution?

Code:

```perl
use Archive::Zip;
use feature qw(say);

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
$zip->read("<PATH_TO_ZIP>");

my $members_ref = $zip->{'members'};
my @members = @$members_ref;

# Not sorted 1st member:
say @members[0]->fileName();

@members = sort { $b->fileName() cmp $a->fileName() } @members;

# Sorted 1st member:
say @members[0]->fileName();

# Should be sorted 1st member if sorted in-place:
say @{$zip->{'members'}}[0]->fileName();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand your problem. Of course you can sort an array reference in-place if you sort that array reference. In your program, you create a copy of the array, and sort that array. The original array remains unsorted.

The following program eliminates the array copy and works for me:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Archive::Zip;
use feature qw(say);

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
$zip->read("Q:/cygwin_tools.zip");

my $members_ref = $zip->{'members'};

# Not sorted 1st member:
say $members_ref->[0]->fileName();

@$members_ref = sort { $b->fileName() cmp $a->fileName() } @$members_ref;

# Sorted 1st member:
say $members_ref->[0]->fileName();

# Should be sorted 1st member if sorted in-place:
say @{$zip->{'members'}}[0]->fileName();

__END__
cygwin/
cygwin/usr/share/bison.simple
cygwin/usr/share/bison.simple
```

#### See also

[perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

[References Quick Reference](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927)

Comment: Thank you, it works this way! I didn't realize that `my @members = @$members_ref;` creates an array copy (this is my first Perl program).