# Perl : Sort array element in alphabetical order

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I have a big array and I want to sort all the elements of the array in alphabetical order.

In a previous subroutine, the element of the array are being pushed to tc_reg array.

I have an array named @tc_lane. When I print element of the array it would look something like this

```
tx0_abc
rx0_fgw
ref_ghv
..
```

Now I want to sort this array like this,

```
ref_ghv
rx0_fgw
tx_abc
..
```

Comment: `@arr = sort @arr;` - please delete this question.

Comment: @SeanBright why delete?  it's a simple question, but with a little bit of looking I don't see any existing question it duplicates; most sort questions are dealing with more complicated situations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Perl array in place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163064/sort-perl-array-in-place)

Comment: That's sorting an array in place where you have a reference to the array instead of an array variable

Comment: From the linked answer: _"Perl allows arrays to be sorted in-place with the idiom `@arr = sort @arr`."_ - which is precisely the answer you gave. So I'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: Why do you want to sort the array ? Getting rid of duplicates ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want

```
rx0_fgw
rx10_fgw
rx2_fgw
```

use

```
my @sorted = sort @unsorted;
```

---

If you want

```
rx0_fgw
rx2_fgw
rx10_fgw
```

use

```
use Sort::Key::Natural qw( natsort );

my @sorted = natsort @unsorted;
```

Comment: Both of these solutions assumes the only letters are lowercase ASCII letters. Other solutions might be needed in other situations.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to do:

```
@tc_lane = sort @tc_lane;
```